# org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot

All,

I am trying to crate the datasource for Oracle DB using Spring Boot. I am getting the following error:

org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

I did look at the different stackoverflow questions on similar questions but nothing worked.

here is the sample code and other artifacts:

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <version>12.2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ucp</artifactId>
    <version>12.2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ons</artifactId>
    <version>12.2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

application.yml:

```
spring:
  oracle-db:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:<oracle db details>
    username: <user id>
    password: <password>
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

In the above I even tried oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver as driver-class-name. I changed the driver-class-name to driverClassName also but same error.

In the code I am creating the datasource as follows:

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.oracle-db")
public DataSourceProperties myDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.oracle-db")
public HikariDataSource getMyds() {
    return myDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
}
```

What is that I am missing?

Comment: How are you running the app? Maybe application.yml is not copied from the resources folder? If you debug `initializeDataSourceBuilder` what's in your DataSourceProperties? Looks like neither the `url` nor the `driverClassName` properties are being set.

Comment: Remove the bean for the `DataSourceProperties` you don't need it as you can directly bind in the builder. As also shown in the [Spring Boot Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-configure-a-datasource). But why aren't you simply using the default `spring.datasource` namespace? Do you need 2 datasources?

Comment: @Strelok, When I did debug on the `initializeDataSourceBuilder` I see that the application.yml is read and values taken from that.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I tried as you suggested but still the same issue. I was going through the Spring Documentation before posting here. I not sure if I am missing any other configuration or any possible conflicts happening in my app. Let me try a plain springboot app with just oracle connectivity and see if its working.

Comment: You also shouldn't need the `driver-class-name` property as that will be derived from the URL.